# How to run gradle on windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, gradle

How to convert existing Maven project to Gradle project?

I read many answers in for the same. But I'm stuck at a point and don't know how to proceed.

Steps I followed:

1. installed Gradle 2.7
2. Added Gradle home and path in environment
3. checked Gradle -v cmd from C: directory. Working fine.
4. trying to run Gradle init command from project directory. NONE OF THE GRADLE CMD IS WORKING FROM PROJECT DIRECTORY. "Gradle CMD not recognised". My project is a complete maven spring cloud stream project.

Kindly let me know what I might be doing wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: Why try to use Gradle 2.7 if the current latest version is Gradle 6.3? If you have a Java version newer than Java 8, Gradle 2.7 will likely not work (or not correctly). In any case, please provide the exact command you used and the exact output from that command.

Comment: Please add more details on the commands you ran and the output you got. Paste the whole terminal output into your question, not just the messages.